# Theta function equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, fourier-series, theta-functions

I have been trying to prove an equation of a theta function.
I understood that it some how related to the Poisson summation formula, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

[the exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw8l4.png)

Comment: You should compute the Fourier-Transform and use the Poisson-Summation Formula.

Comment: Could you be more specific pls?
I didn't understand what f and g are

Comment: Writing $f(x) = \exp(-\pi Y[x] t)$, we have $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d} f(n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}^d} \widehat{f}(n)$ by Poisson summation formula. So we are left to determine $\widehat{f}$. By change for variables this can be reduced to the Fourier-Transform of $x \mapsto \exp(-\pi \|x\|^2)$. And for this special case you should know that the Fourier transform is again the same function.

Comment: Could you say what is $Y[a]$, and where does Y lie?